# Lucene: get results where field 1 matches, UNLESS field 2 also matches

Tags: lucene

Supposing I a have a set of documents in lucene, and I have a current result `X`, and `X` has a `familyID` and `threadID`.  Is it possible to write a query which expresses:

```
results where result.threadID is X.threadID AND (result.familyID is not X.family ID, UNLESS result.ID is X.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

A coworker came across the answer:

```
(threadID:X.threadID -familyID:X.familyID) id:x.ID
```